# Routing Issue in MVC with multiple action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
 public ActionResult Browse(string country , string serachQuery , int?  jobCategoryId , string jobCategory)
    {
    }
```

**Routing**

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "search",
            url: "Job/Browse/{country}/{serachQuery}/{jobCategoryId}/{jobCategory}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Job", action = "Browse", country = UrlParameter.Optional, serachQuery = UrlParameter.Optional, jobCategoryId = UrlParameter.Optional, jobCategory = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );



        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Job", action = "Browse" }
            );
```

Link 1

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Browse", new{   jobCategoryId = Model.JobCategoryList[i].LookUpId ,  jobCategory=  Gulfjobs.Common.Convert.ToSeoUrl(Model.JobCategoryList[i].Value )})" >@Model.JobCategoryList[i].Value</a>
```

above link URL display as 
http://{domain}/?jobCategoryId=13&jobCategory=hotel

Link 2

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Browse","Job", new { country=  @country.Value })">@country.Value</a>
```

above link display as

```
http://{domain}/Job/Browse/Dubai
```

how to display link 1 like below

http://{URL}/Job/Browse/12/engineers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a crucial information, which is that you cannot use an optional route parameter if at least one previous optional parameter is missing.

So with the route definition you have provided, following routes are possible:

- Job/Browse/{country}/{serachQuery}/{jobCategoryId}/{jobCategory}
- Job/Browse/{country}/{serachQuery}/{jobCategoryId}
- Job/Browse/{country}/{serachQuery}
- Job/Browse/{country}
- Job/Browse

Routes below are not possible (some examples):

- Job/Browse/{jobCategodyId}
- Job/Browse/{serachQuery}/{jobCategory}

  etc...

My first suggestion would be that you check http://attributerouting.net . Using that, you can make it possible depending on if you can define additional constraints on your route parameters.

So for example, {country} is a string. I guess {searchQuery} is a string too. But {jobCategoryId} is an int.

Thus you can define a new route, Job/Browse/{jobCategoryId?:int}/{jobCategory?}. This would not conflict with your first route, because {country} is a string and {jobCategoryId} is definitely an int. With AttributeRouting, you can make use of regex too.

I guess you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Change your link

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Browse", new{country="/",serachQuery ="/",jobCategoryId = Model.JobCategoryList[i].LookUpId ,  jobCategory=  Gulfjobs.Common.Convert.ToSeoUrl(Model.JobCategoryList[i].Value )})" >@Model.JobCategoryList[i].Value</a>
```